# Character set in Linux filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, arch-linux, character-encoding

I just installed some Arch Linux packages, which dumped this file onto my disk:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.pem
```

Note that the file name seems to contain Turkish characters. Here are different commands with their output:

```
> cd /etc/ssl/certs
> echo EBG*
EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.pem
> ls -al EBG*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 86 Nov  3 22:27 EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa??lay??c??s??.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa??lay??c??s??.crt
```

Q1: Why do `echo` and `ls` produce different output?

So it's a symlink. If I dereference it:

```
> ls -alL EBG*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2106 Sep 24 22:52 EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa??lay??c??s??.pem
```

Let's look at the target:

```
> cd /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla
> echo EBG*
EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sağlayıcısı.crt
> ls -al EBG*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2106 Sep 24 22:52 EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa??lay??c??s??.crt
```

Q2: What is the encoding used for non-ASCII characters in a Linux file system (here: ext4)? Am I correct that the encoding is not captured anywhere, and if I give you some random hard drive without instructions, you need to guess which encoding I used?

I noticed there was a problem because `pacman` (the Arch Linux package manager) seemed to get confused about whether or not it had installed that file:

Q3: How do I prevent `pacman`, or `ls`, or anything else from getting confused about files like that? What if next week, some file is arabic or hebrew instead of Turkish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `echo` is a dumb program, which produces output whether or not it thinks it makes sense. `ls` is a smart program, which tries to output only what makes sense in context. This results in `ls` producing the "wrong" output because you haven't set up your locale correctly. If you `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` (or some other language with utf-8) then `ls` will display it correctly; normally there is some system environment script that does this.
2. Linux filesystems do not enforce a encoding (but foreign mounted ones may perform encoding transormations, e.g. from cp1252 for FAT), but by strong convention it is always utf-8. For the past several years it has been considered a severe bug if any other encoding is used in a package.
3. For `ls`, fix your environment. For `pacman`, file a bug.

Comment: Ah! To add, the locale needs to exist, so on Arch, uncomment `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 ` in `/etc/locale.gen` and run `sudo locale-gen`.